# ChartJS - Highlight grouped bars

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I have a table with the following data structure:

```
if ($("#demo-bar-chart").length) {  
var gpdData = {
"labels": ["2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"],
"datasets": [
    {
        "label": "China",
        "fillColor": "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        "strokeColor": "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        "highlightFill": "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        "highlightStroke": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        "data": [0.5,11,2,3]
    },
    {
        "label": "India",
        "fillColor": "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        "strokeColor": "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        "highlightFill": "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        "highlightStroke": "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
         "data": [1,9,4,6]
    }  
]
}
```

The 2016 figures are forecasted figures and I would like to highlight the COLUMN not each bar. To group them and show a visual separation. Though I can't seem to find anything in the API to enable column background-color.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to change COLUMN  background

Comment: Can't see COLUMN in the API... Have you got a fiddle to reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the bar chart to draw the highlight over the columns. It would be better to make the start from highlight an option that you can pass in (highlightFromIndex in the below code)

HTML

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

JS

```
Chart.types.Bar.extend({
    name: "BarAlt",
    draw: function () {
        Chart.types.Bar.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

        // overlay the highlight
        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        var scale = this.scale;
        var xColumnWidth = (scale.width - scale.xScalePaddingLeft - scale.xScalePaddingRight) / scale.xLabels.length
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)'
        ctx.fillRect(
            scale.xScalePaddingLeft + xColumnWidth * this.options.highlightFromIndex,
            scale.startPoint,
            xColumnWidth * (scale.xLabels.length - this.options.highlightFromIndex + 1),
            scale.endPoint - scale.startPoint)
    }
});


var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");

var gpdData = {
    "labels": ["2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"],
    "datasets": [
        {
            "label": "China",
            "fillColor": "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            "strokeColor": "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            "highlightFill": "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            "highlightStroke": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            "data": [0.5, 11, 2, 3]
        },
        {
            "label": "India",
            "fillColor": "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            "strokeColor": "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            "highlightFill": "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            "highlightStroke": "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            "data": [1, 9, 4, 6]
        }
    ]
}

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).BarAlt(gpdData, {
    highlightFromIndex: 3
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/smLcr3v4/